# Dart Resources monitor

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I want to make a app that shows the phone resources for following:

1. Battery Level
2. Memory Usage
3. Storage Usage
4. CPU Usage

Is that possible?

Do anyone know how to do this or did this?
(and could help me)

Comment: for the battery level looks like it's possible to use this Android API: https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with the help of a few dependencies.
Here's the [community plus packages](https://plus.fluttercommunity.dev/), and a few of them will help you fetch the battery level and some other devices information.

You can import the packages in your `pubspec.yaml` and start implementing them in your code.